# Run jQuery function on pageload and repeat with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/438/

This is a small segment from a slot machine I'm running on a webpage. As of right now, it won't do anything until you click the button. I'm looking however to execute this script on a pageload or probably rather a window.onload, since all the images need to be loaded first. But it can NOT replace the clickable button. The button should still work after the first spin has completed (the one on the page load)

jQuery, this is where the script knows when to start running, I think. As you can see, it will run the second a button with the playBtn ID is clicked:

```
var clickCount = 0;
var jsSlot;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#playBtn").click(function() {
        if (!jsSlot.isSpinning) {
            clickCount++;
            if (clickCount == 2)
            {
                jsSlot.options.endNumbers = [1, 4, 6]; //<----- Different end numbers for second click
            }
            else
            {
                 jsSlot.options.endNumbers = [1, 4, 3]; //<----- Different end numbers for other clicks
            }
        }
    });

    jsSlot = $('.slot').jSlots({
                spinner: '#playBtn',
                winnerNumber: 7,
                endNumbers: [1, 4, 3] //<----- Added endNumbers option
            })[0];

});
```

HTML, and here is that button:

```
<input type="button" value="test" id="playBtn" />
```

I did some research first, but I think I need to make a pageload simulate a click, rather than execute the script, because the script won't do anything until the button is actually clicked.

So am I looking for something like this?

```
$(window).load(function () {
         somehow pretend to click ("#playBtn")
});
```

Comment: Taking a look at the jquery documentation, you would easily see the answer yourself: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger elements on purpose.

Try it by:

```
$(window).load(function () {
            $("#playBtn").trigger("click");
});
```

[Here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3j4/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You click after the window is loaded

Try this

```
$(window).load(function () {
         $("#playBtn").click();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3fZV/440/)